# Boolean is accepting numeric values like 0, 1 ,1234

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a Boolean wrapper field in my POJO class.And this POJO class in mapped with request in @RestController class. I want to accept only true or false from request parameter.Any value apart from the true or false should not allow.But when I testing through postman,
my Boolean wrapper in my POJO class is accepting 0,1,1234• 0 as a false, 1 as a true,  1234 as a true.And also it accepting "true","false" in quotes.  I want to restrict all this unnecessary value.
I tried to use @Pattern annotation to match these values. But it not works.
Any idea how to validate this in Java.

Comment: That might just be out of the box implementation. You need to track down the registered HandlerMethodArgumentResolver implementations to find out the specific rules playing role in conversion.

Comment: When asking question, avoid describing requirements in many words that could be described more accurately and simply with a little code

Comment: Exactly what should happen when the wrong value is passed?